# Getting URLError Exception when caching webdriver instances

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to cache webdriver instances across test case classes. I do not need a "clean" webdriver since I am simply using PhantomJS to query the DOM (I do need JavaScript enabled, which is why I am not simply fetching the source and parsing that).

The cache is a dictionary with the URL as a key and the driver instance as value. The cache is in the base test case, and I call get() which is a method on the base test case. This method instantiates webdriver, and goes to the url if the driver is not in the cache already.

It appears there's some kind of socket issue when trying to access driver properties on the cached instance in the second test case (derivedb.py). I'd appreciate if someone could tell how to get this work.

I am getting the following output:

```
$ python launcher.py
test_a (deriveda.DerivedTestCaseA) ... Instantiate new driver
Title is: Google
ok
test_b (deriveda.DerivedTestCaseA) ... Retrieve driver from cache
Title is: Google
ok
test_a (derivedb.DerivedTestCaseB) ... Retrieve driver from cache
ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: test_a (derivedb.DerivedTestCaseB)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cohenaa/PycharmProjects/sanity/derivedb.py", line 7, in test_a
    print "Title is: %s" % self.driver.title
  File "/Users/cohenaa/sanity-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 185, in title
    resp = self.execute(Command.GET_TITLE)
  File "/Users/cohenaa/sanity-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 162, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/Users/cohenaa/sanity-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 349, in execute
    return self._request(url, method=command_info[0], data=data)
  File "/Users/cohenaa/sanity-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 410, in _request
    resp = opener.open(request)
  File "/sw/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/sw/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/sw/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/sw/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/sw/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 61] Connection refused>

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 1.271s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

**launcher.py**

```
import unittest
from deriveda import DerivedTestCaseA
from derivedb import DerivedTestCaseB

suite = unittest.TestSuite()
testclasses = [DerivedTestCaseA, DerivedTestCaseB]
testloader = unittest.TestLoader()
classes_to_names = {}
for tc in testclasses:
    classes_to_names[tc] = testloader.getTestCaseNames(tc)

for tc in classes_to_names:
    for testname in classes_to_names[tc]:
        suite.addTest(tc(testname))
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=10).run(suite)
```

**deriveda.py**

```
from basetestcase import BaseTestCase
from unittest import main

class DerivedTestCaseA(BaseTestCase):

    def test_a(self):
        self.get("http://www.google.com")
        print "Title is: %s" % self.driver.title
    def test_b(self):
        self.get("http://www.google.com")
        print "Title is: %s" % self.driver.title
```

**derivedb.py**

```
from basetestcase import BaseTestCase

class DerivedTestCaseB(BaseTestCase):

    def test_a(self):
        self.get("http://www.google.com")
        print "Title is: %s" % self.driver.title
```

**basetestcase.py:**

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    cache = {}
    def get(self, url):
        if url not in self.cache:
            print "Instantiate new driver"
            self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS() 
            self.driver.get(url)
            self.cache[url] = self.driver
        else:
            print "Retrieve driver from cache"
            self.driver = self.cache[url]

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        for url in BaseTestCase.cache:
            BaseTestCase.cache[url].quit()
```

Comment: So using my debugger and switching to Firefox I get a similar exception on line 871 in httplib. It's checking that the state is idle. Inspecting I see it's "Request-sent". In the else clause it raises an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh. I see now. The driver is quitting after each test case. If I quit after the suite is run instead, no error.